# error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type (MEX, Windows 10)

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am using mex to implement C++ codes in MATLAB on Windows 10.
I want to modify the elements of a 2D array that I created but I keep getting this error.
Below are the codes and the error message.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

// net.idx_phiz{m}(:,1:num_v) => get_index(net.idx_phiz{m}, num_v)

extern "C" void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    //receive value and create output variable
    auto& matrix = prhs[0];
    auto& size = prhs[1];
    auto& out = plhs[0];

    //get size
    auto m = mxGetM(matrix);
    auto n = mxGetPr(size)[0];

    //get value
    auto val = mxGetPr(matrix);

    //create output pointer
    out = mxCreateNumericMatrix(m, n, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    auto B = (double*)mxGetPr(out);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            B[i][j] = val[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

From the last line, I get the error as below:

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

I looked up past discussions but they are usually the error C2109 not pertaining to mex. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `B` is a `double *`, so `B[i]` is a `double` and you can't use the subscript on a `double`, like `B[i][j]` would do. Not sure what you actually want to do. Probably depends on the return type of `mxGetPr`.

Comment: The matrix elements are stored in one-dimensional arrays of size m*n.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, your solution is right. This was my first time asking a question here, and I hope you know that I am sincerely thankful for your kind advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect, `B` and `val` are pointers to `double`, and therefore cannot be indexed twice, only once.

```
B[i][j] = val[i][j];
```

Think of the data in a MATLAB array as a 1D array, where the columns of the logical array are stacked. Given `m` rows and `n` columns, one can obtain the location in memory for the matrix element (`i`,`j`) with `i + m*j`. Consequently, your copy operation should read:

```
B[i + m*j] = val[i + m*j];
```

---

However, the above is likely to lead to problems since `n` is given by a second argument, and there is no guarantee that the input matrix has than many columns. You need to add an explicit test to verify that `matrix` has at least `n` columns, and that it is a double-valued matrix (if it is, for example, of type `single` you'll be reading out of bounds as well, since `mxGetPr` always returns a pointer to `double`, not matter what the data in the array actually is.

Comment: Your answers are accurate and even far-sighted. How did u know that I had a problem with ```mxGetPr```? It took like few hours for me to realize that the input should be double for ```mxGetPr``` yesterday. You have my respect.